# Bronze Badge Request: Confident

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badge-request

Could there be a badge for posting a post that was initially negatively scored, while within, say 24 hours of posting, its score rose to be positive, without editing the post *(meaning there isn't really a flaw to edit)*?

I know it's generally frowned upon to delete a post due to downvotes, but it does happen... a lot. This bronze badge should encourage users who posted a potentially good post, that got downvoted at first, to resist the urge to delete their post immediately.

It's to remind users that

“That downvote doesn't necessarily mean that my post is worthless. The score might rise to be positive soon.”

Of course, your posts are never worthless, despite downvotes.

This badge may only be awarded if there have been no comments on the post, such as ones pointing out the fault of the post *(if there is any fault at all)*.

Comment: Badges are meant to encourage desirable behavior. Disregarding feedback is generally not that.

Comment: positive score doesn't also mean good or correct answer.

Comment: I disagree with *"your posts are never worthless"*. There are numerous worthless posts here on a daily basis

Comment: The theme of this badge brings to my mind a famous quote by Bertrand Russell.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica You mean [this](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/367-do-not-fear-to-be-eccentric-in-opinion-for-every)?

Comment: @yivi *"Disregarding feedback is generally not that."* I agree. But the feedback is not always accurate at the first minute, which potential further feedback won't be possible if the post gets deleted by then.

Comment: @AnnZen - Nah, you know which one I mean. Though I do tend to see the one you brought be prompted as a sort of fig leaf by the folks Russel mentions in his other one :)

Comment: Less of confident & more of competent & conformant please.

Comment: Badges are only ever awarded automatically, i.e. without human intervention. There's no reasonable way the *usefulness* of a comment can be automatically evaluated. I think you might need to rethink exactly what this badge would achieve, and how it would be awarded.

Comment: If a post gets any downvotes, it is much more likely that it  needs improvement than that the poster should not improve it. Also a downvoted post may not have received a comment but it has received a canned feedback that it has problems. So reasoning that the badge be limited to no comments applies to no downvotes, so the badge should never be awarded & shouldn't exist. This proposal is predicated on the fantasy that people downvote for no good reason a meaningful fraction of the time.

Comment: @cigien "no comments", not "no useful comments". I only added the "such as" to put emphasis on the point.

Comment: I like the idea. It can be hard to not delete a question or answer that immediately gets hit with a few downvotes. But it is rather satisfying when days, weeks, months, years later, it has moved into the positive and working its way up the ranks. But maybe that satisfaction is the only reward needed.

Comment: I agree, this happens, I faced it several times, some didn't become positive, but I'm on your side, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70593084/bug-with-scrollable-tabs-in-bootstrap-5

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70441067/unable-to-call-a-js-function-from-typescript-in-angular-13

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70186639/nullinjectorerror-no-provider-for-matbottomsheet

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68390589/how-to-auto-adjust-the-height-of-a-webview-in-xamarin-android-or-android-based

The worst is that I didn't get any comment and needed an answer.

Comment: @yivi I agree, and I think many existing badges ought to be pruned on that basis.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think this badge is a good idea, because it incentivizes and rewards a behavior that is generally negative, in this case, ignoring feedback.

When a post is downvoted and/or gets comments about how it should be improved, the OP should *definitely* take that feedback into account, and strive to improve that post if at all possible. If a post *only* gets downvotes, and no constructive feedback in comments, then I agree it's harder to know what improvements to make. Nonetheless, the existence of this badge would send the wrong message.

The [argument against badges that incentivize negative behavior](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/12/16/badges-positive-only) has been put forward very nicely by Jeff, and I think the linked comic by Scott Meyer in that blogpost puts it even more nicely:

[image]

---

In the case of your "Confident" badge, I fear that this would simply get used as a "Stubborn" badge:

> hey lookie here, I asked a question, and got a badge for ignoring everyone's suggestions to improve it :)

This is definitely not behavior or an attitude we want to encourage, or even give the *appearance* of encouraging.

---

As to your last comment, while a downvote doesn't necessarily mean that a post is worthless, and I'm all for being encouraging and supportive, I'm afraid there are quite a few posts on Stack Overflow that *are* worthless. I don't mean "worthless" in any profound, philosophical sense, but only that they are worthless when it comes to adding them to Stack Overflow's repository of questions and answers, and downvotes are a good way to express this.

Comment: *"And gets comments about how they should improve it,"* That would mean that the post is flawed, hence it won't reach a positive score no matter how long the user waits, meaning no badge will be awarded.

Comment: @AnnZen Not necessarily. Flawed posts get upvoted, and reach positive scores, for a number of reasons such as having a catchy title, or being an interesting topic for some people. The posts may still need improvement, and incentivizing ignoring those comments sends the wrong message I think.

Comment: I see. But votes aren't comments...

Comment: @AnnZen Oh, are you suggesting this specifically for posts that are downvoted, but have received no comments?

Comment: Yes. ----------

Comment: @AnnZen I see. I read your proposal as being ignoring *any* feedback. Please edit your question to make that caveat clear. I still think downvotes are feedback that shouldn't be ignored, but I guess it's not clear *how* to improve a post if downvotes are the *only* provided feedback.